# .reg file downloads from web site as MP3 in Internet Explorer?

Tags: file, internet-explorer, firefox, download, registry

I have a custom .reg file, which is used to apply registry adjustments.  Making it a download is causing Internet Explorer ad FireFox to treat it as a media file, or download it as an MP3?

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: no.. you are downloading from your site..?? i mean you have developed your own downloading sample or its an external published site?? may be they have something wrong with header content type..

Comment: Its a downloadable file from the site yes, but its being renamed.  I know its to do with MINE types, but I want to prevent this from happening.

Comment: from client side you can not change the header of response... including MINE types.. so i think its not possible to play with the header of response you are getting on download file action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Needed to add MIME type support to my Apache Web Server:

Using the following configuration:

AddType text/plain .reg

Answer (score 0):

I changed .htaccess to:

```
AddType text/text .reg
```

It did the trick for Firefox and IE. In IE I didn't even have to download the file. Clicking it sent it directly to the registry (after ample warnings). When I changed it to `text/plain` it appended `.txt` in Firefox.